# Как проверить наличие скобок { } в файле?

Tags: файлы, c++

И как вывести содержимое ,заключающееся в них ,в файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в лоб в стиле Си, только без рекурсивных скобок.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fin = fopen("in.txt", "rt");
    if(fin == NULL)
         return 1;

    char  fnm[] = "out.txt";
    FILE* fout  = fopen(fnm, "wt+");

    int  n;
    long f, l;
    while(! feof(fin)) {

         n = 0;
         fscanf(fin, "%*[^{]%*c%n", &n);
         if(feof(fin))
             break;

         if(! n) {
             if(fgetc(fin) != '{')
                 continue;
         }
         f = ftell(fin);

         fscanf(fin, "%*[^}]");
         if(feof(fin))
               break;
         l = ftell(fin);
         fseek(fin, f, SEEK_SET);

         for(long i = l - f; i > 0L; --i)
              fputc(fgetc(fin), fout);
         fputc('\n', fout); // для разделение
    }
    fclose(fin);

    if(! ftell(fout)) {
        fclose(fout);
        unlink(fnm);
    } else {
        fflush(fout);
        fclose(fout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   с = getc() ; 
   if (c == 123 || c == 125){  
  //счетчик ++  
  }
```

Увидела первую скобку(123) в цикле for()- начинаешь выводить,увидела вторую скобку(125) - заканчиваешь выводить.

Comment: А почему не просто `if (c == '{')`?

Comment: А какая кстати разница между моей строкой и вашей?

Comment: @Якоби, вашу Татьяна не сможет объяснить на зачете (уж не знаю, плюс это или минус)

Comment: @Fike более того, это не очевидно, и вообще никто не гарантирует, что символы скобок будут иметь именно такие числовые значения. И еще более того, вариант с кодами и вовсе не дает преимуществ, чтобы ради них можно было чем-то жертвовать

Comment: @Якоби Этот <s>говнокод</s>антипаттерн называется "магические числа".

Comment: Помимо всего прочего, у этого кода есть и еще одно слабое место - если в файле нет закрывающей скобки, то произойдет вообще хрен знает что вплоть до краха приложения. Ну и в качестве вишенки на торте - если в файле имеются вложенные скобки, то скорее всего будет прочитано  некорректное содержимое (впрочем, не факт - зависит от постановки задачи)